# How to create a conditional field in logstash?

Tags: logstash

I have a field called "Priority" which has integer values like 1 to
10. Here 1 is the lowest and 10 is the highest. How to show string
values, rather than, numbers to make this field more understandable. So new field should contain 3 values i.e

```
low ---> if priority lies in 1 to 3
Medium---> if priority lies in 4-7
high---->if priority lies in 8-10
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to assure that your priority value is of type `int`. After that you can use [logstash's conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html) to change the value into a string.

**Example Configuration:**

```
input { stdin {} }
filter {
    grok { match => { "message" => [" %{NUMBER:priority:int}" ] } }
    if [priority] < 4 {
        mutate { replace => { "priority" => "low" } } 
    } else if [priority] < 8 {
        mutate { replace => { "priority" => "medium" } }
    } else {
        mutate { replace => { "priority" => "high" } }
    }
}
output {stdout { codec => rubydebug }}
```

Please note the [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_grok_basics) which parses your number into a field of type `int`.

```
%{NUMBER:priority:int}
```

That means, wherever you get your priority field from, you need to take care that it contains an int. Otherwise you could do this by comparing string values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you keep two fields: both the numeric and the string (pretty) version.  That way, you can run efficient queries based on the number and display the string on your charts, etc.

More info [here](http://svops.com/blog/handling-log-levels-in-logstash/).